# How to avoid stack overflow errors when defining set accessor in C#

Tags: c#, get, set, stack-overflow

People of stackoverflow.  I am new to c# and this is the first time I have not been able to find an answer to one of my elementary questions. Who can help me?!I am trying to define set logic for a public instance field.

*This runs flawlessly,*

> public string Headline {get; set;}

*This results in stack overflow*

> public string Headline
>   { 
>       get 
>       {
>           return Headline;
>       }
>       set
>       {
>           Headline = value;
>       } 
>   }

Comment: Why do you need the setter at all? The usual thing people do here is define a private variable and use that in the setter, and read from it in the getter. However, you don't seem to need it here, just use the auto-implemented property you've already got.

Comment: Your property setter is calling the property setter. If you step through this in the debugger, it'll be much more obvious what's going on.

Answer (score 15):

You're calling the getter and setter recursively (calling themselves infinitely), inevitably causing a stack overflow.

Surely this is what you mean to be doing:

```
private string headline;
public string Headline
{
    get { return headline; }
    set { headline = value; }
}
```

Note that this is unnecessary if you don't plan to introduce any further get/set logic, as this is exactly what your first example does behind the scenes.

When learning about properties in c#, it helps to think of them not as data, but as a pair of methods with the following signatures:

```
public string get_Headline() { ... }
public void set_Headline(string value) { ... }
```

In fact, this is exactly how the compiler defines them.

Now it's easy to see that your initial code would call `set_Headline` recursively.

Answer (score 4):

You need a backing field if you are trying to use `set` and `get` with your property.

```
private string _headline; //backing field.

public string Headline
{
    get { return _headline; }
    set { _headline = value; }
}
```

In your current code, you are trying to set your property recursively, and thus resulting in stackoverflow exception

Answer (score 3):

Because you're returning the same thing recursively.

```
private string _headLine

public string Headline
{ 
   get 
   { return _headline; } 
   set 
   { _headline = value; } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case instead of generating a new variable like the rest of the answers are saying. You can simply just write.

```
public string Headline { get; set;}
```

This will allow anyone to retrieve this variable which you could re write as

```
public string Headline;
```

If you want the setting to be private you can say.

```
public string Headline { get; private set; }
```

I like it this way better because this way you don't have to allocate a new variable and the readability of the code greatly increases :)